# Querying JSON in SQL Server

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I want to query a JSON string in SQL Server 2019.

Unfortunately, I couldn't solve the issue with the `JSON_VALUE` [expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql?source=recommendations&view=sql-server-ver16#lax-mode-and-strict-mode), since it seems to expect a variable name before each curly brackets.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

```
[
    {
        "Name": "name1",
        "Val": 1
    },
    {
        "Name": "name2",
        "Val": 2
    }
]
```

Comment: Try `OPENJSON`. `JSON_VALUE` is for individual values, you've got an array of them instead.

Comment: `JSON_VALUE()` works just fine with valid JSON, e.g.: `SELECT JSON_VALUE(@json, '$[0].Val') as Val0;`. The problem is you don't have valid JSON: comma characters `,` seperate elements and should not appear before `}` or `]` characters. Ref: [Introducing JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html).

Comment: @AlwaysLearning You were right - I added a wrong ``,`` before ``}`` in my example. This is not the case. I just correted it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Jeroen Mostert! `OPENJSON` instead of `JSON_VALUE` solved the problem.